# C - extracting all Numbers from string

Tags: c, while-loop, segmentation-fault, double, strtod

I got a String like by reading a file which got online one line. The C is a separator between the numbers.

```
3000C9.5452C5.644 ...
```

Now I want to extract all those numbers and write them into an double array whichs is called Matrix.

```
fgets(input_string, filesize, infile);
int matrix_size = (int) strtof(input_string, &input_end);
++input_string;
int binary_matrix_size = sizeof (double)*(matrix_size * matrix_size);
double *Matrix = malloc(binary_matrix_size);
for (int index = 0; index < (matrix_size * matrix_size); ++index) {
        while (!isdigit(input_string) && input_string) {
            ++input_string;
        }
        Matrix[index] = strtod(input_string, &input_end);
        input_string = input_end;
}
```

Comment: Which kind of floating pouint number is `3000C9.5452C5.644`..??

Comment: You can check specific range of numbers from ASCII table, which is 0x30 - 0x39 (1-9) and if you recognize it, just replace them with appropriate integer numbers.

Comment: `while (!isdigit(input_string) && input_string)` --> should be `while (!isdigit(*input_string) && (*input_string != '\0') && input_string )` BTW I really don't know what your code is supposed to do...

Comment: Edit so that my problem is potentially more clear.

Comment: It is not clear, because: Why are you using strtof to extract the array size? Why are you allocating a matrix if you need an array? Your for must iterate matrix_size times. The while must be changed as I posted before.....

Comment: The array size seems to be an integer (erm, yes, what else)- You are expecting a float, which does not make a lot of sense. And: You are not actually asking a question, do you?

Comment: If `C` is the separator, code should look for `C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to understand what you need.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *input_string = "2C9.5452C5.644";
    char *input_end;

    int matrix_size = strtol(input_string, &input_end, 10);
    printf("Array size: %d\n", matrix_size);
    input_string = input_end;
    double *Matrix = malloc(sizeof(double)*(matrix_size));
    for (int index = 0; index < matrix_size; ++index) {
            while ( (*input_string != '\0') && !isdigit(*input_string) && input_string ) {
                ++input_string;
            }
            Matrix[index] = strtod(input_string, &input_end);
            printf("Retrieved value: %f\n", Matrix[index]);
            input_string = input_end;
    }

    free(Matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Array size: 2
Retrieved value: 9.545200
Retrieved value: 5.644000
```

Comment: That's indeed what i need. But the output was "Array size: 2
Retrieved value: 0.000000
Retrieved value: 0.000000"

Comment: @SvenBamberger Output is as posted.... This is an example. You posted `3000C9.5452C5.644`: I haven't got 3K values....

Comment: I used your example. Is there any special compiler Option or so?

Comment: @SvenBamberger I compiled with: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic test.c -o test  -std=c99`

Comment: I compiled with your options. and still getting `Array size: 2
Retrieved value: 0.000000
Retrieved value: 0.000000
`

Comment: @chux I'm too tired to understand your comment. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

LPs answer is correct; however, strtod requires stdlib.h (no idea why it runs on LPs's

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char *input_string = "2C9.5452C5.644";
    char *input_end;
    int index = 0;

    int matrix_size = strtol(input_string, &input_end, 10);
    printf("Array size: %d\n", matrix_size);
    ++input_string;
    int binary_matrix_size = sizeof(double)*(matrix_size);
    double *Matrix = malloc(binary_matrix_size);
    for (index = 0; index < matrix_size; ++index) {
        while ( (*input_string != '\0') && !isdigit(*input_string) && input_string ) {
            ++input_string;
        }
        Matrix[index] = strtod(input_string, &input_end);
        printf("Retrieved value: %f\n", Matrix[index]);
        input_string = input_end;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It was added at the top of file I used to use to check temp code. Thx

Comment: the posted answer will fail if the first character in a new number is a`.` as the `while()` loop will step over that.  Since the input format is known.  suggest replacing the `while()` loop with: `input_string++;` to simply step over the `C` separator